# How PCA implemeted in ClustofVar package and how to determine ranking of each column?

Tags: r, clustering, pca, hierarchical-clustering

I am clustering columns of the Titanic dataset (Has 7 columns) using ClustofVar package https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v050i13

Columns in the dataset are clustered as shown in the Dendrogram https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOAL8.jpg. I want to know which columns effect the survial column.

From dendrogram, The surival & sex of person are clustered closely. So, I understand these two columns (survial & sex) are highly related.

Sex is for sure highly related to survival column. What is the next best column that effects survival column ? Do i look at the next high correlation value ? Correlation values changing with the number of clusters I cut the tree into.

The below snippet cuts the Dendrogram into 3 clusters that shows the squared correlations as https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8sr.jpg.  When i cut the dendrogram to 4 clusters, i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGy8S.jpg. How to know how many clusters to cut the dendrogram into ?

```
#Squared loading Correlations 
summary(tree)
tree.cut<-cutreevar(tree,3)
```

I am not quite sure of PCA implemented in `hclustvar` function of the ClustofVar Package. If someone has interest and patience to explain it, would be really helpful :)

PS1: Are there any other algorithms that can give the ranking for columns or can solve my problem more efficiently?

PS2: Till now i am focusing only on unsupervised learning algorithms. Do i need to use supervised learning to achieve what i stated in PS1 ?

Comment: Edited "dendogram" to "dendrogram" throughout. It's a common typo in statistical sciences. It may help to note that the root (a good word in this context) is exactly that also used in the words rhododendron, dendritic and dendrite.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But i dont see the change. Shall i change again to dendrogram ?

Comment: I didnot changed the correct spelling back. I just added some other text.

Comment: We both might be simultaneously editing the text. I finished editing last. That why your edits were not taken preference. Thanks for ur time n effort ;)

Comment: Could be. The edit trail shows my changes being reversed by yours, but as you say yours took preference.

Comment: Yes. I didnot change words corrected by you. I have not even seen your comment of edit while i last completed my editing.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding but "dendogram" remains incorrect.

Comment: Corrected the spelling now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correlation of binary variables and correlation of continuous variables don't compare well. Choose another approach, not correlation of features.
2. You want to *predict*. So use a predictive approach like *classification*, not clustering. As you can see, all that clustering identified is a correlation between sex and survival, it missed everything else. You don't get anything from learning how other features cluster, if you just want to predict survival.
3. Correlations may apply only for subgroups of the data. Your approach will miss any such combination of attributes that is predictive.

Comment: Thanks Anony. As u noted in 1, doing any type of correaltion like pearson, kendall....for binary variables is of no use. Thats why i am using ClustofVar package where it is taking squared correlations for different types of variables. It seems to cluster good. Still as you specified in point 3, I am missing some features to relate the clustered features with.

Comment: Regarding point 2, actually i dont want to predict. There is no missing data  nor i am training the datasets to identify in future if some person dies or not. I want to know each column closeness with another. Something like, sex effects survival by 50%. Age effects survival by 40%. and all other columns ranking w.r.t survival column.

Comment: I tried almost all good unsupervised learning techniques so far. Maybe u r right. Though i dont want to predict, maybe i need classification for my analysis instead of clustering.  Do you know any good package that does this rank based analysis ?

Comment: The reason why i choose clustering instead of supervised learning techniques is to save time.  if i am able to decide what are all the relevant columns that are close to the survival, i can send them later to some random forest to decide the columns closeness probability. But, having no idea of what column to cluster before will lead to more trail and error cases in classification techniques, The time for my feature engineering decreases with clustering. Isnt it ?

Comment: This titanic dataset with 7 columns is just a dummy dataset i showcased. Actual dataset has more than 80 columns. Out of which only 5 or 6 are important and we are not sure what mechanism is good to identify those. I am naive in this area. Please feel free to share your ideas. I would be happy to hear from you.

Comment: "survival" is supervised. Unsupervised is *much* harder, it's not going to save you time.